# Why Unicode Character 'MINUS SIGN' (U+2212) is NOT in regex unicode group \p{Pd} (Dash_Punctuation)?

Tags: regex, unicode

I'm trying to collect all dash-signs to use it while analyzing raw text data. I've found that Unicode regexp `\p{Pd}` should match all cases, but after all, it turned out that this character `−` doesn't match!

Here is more info about this char:
https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm

Is it a bug or a feature? Practically it's not useful stuff.

Answer (score 5):

The Unicode character `U+2212 MINUS SIGN` is a *math*-related symbol, and is probably not considered as a *punctuation* mark; for instance, it is matched by `\p{Math}` but not by `\p{Punctuation}` (which includes `\p{Dash_Punctuation}`).

You may want to try using `\p{Dash}` instead, and check whether it covers all your needs or not...

Ref: [Properties for U+2212](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=2212&B1=Show)

**Edit**:

Here is an "official" list of all the characters having a `Dash` Unicode property: https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/list-unicodeset.jsp?a=[:Dash=Yes:], including the `U+2212 MINUS SIGN` character.

In Unicode 12.0, the JavaScript regular expression:

`/\p{Dash}/u`

would be equivalent to:

`/[\u002D\u058A\u05BE\u1400\u1806\u2010\u2011\u2012\u2013\u2014\u2015\u2053\u207B\u208B\u2212\u2E17\u2E1A\u2E3A\u2E3B\u2E40\u301C\u3030\u30A0\uFE31\uFE32\uFE58\uFE63\uFF0D]/`

Comment: Thanks for response. The problem is that no any supported **regex** to match   _Dash_ (see https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html). So, it's truly unclear to use available regexp _\p{Pd}_ and don't mach this char using this.

Comment: It could be that the `\p{Dash}` property is not available in all regular expressions engines. In JavaScript though, running `node` in a macOS Terminal, or in a Chrome or Safari web browser: `console.log (/\p{Dash}/u.test ("−"));` returns `true`.

Comment: Edited the answer to give the exhaustive list of the 28 Unicode characters considered as dash-signs in Unicode 12.0.

Comment: Great link!  It also gives ordinary regex in square brackets, because in _google re2_, for example, `/\p{Dash}/u` doesn't work. So, for me right practical solution is still using this hand-made expression for all hyphen-like chars:
`[-‐–—‑‒―−－᠆﹘﹣֊⸺⸻]` or this, shorter but with a little garbage:
`[\p{Pd}|−]`