# Regex failing with arabic chars

Tags: javascript, regex, arabic

Im trying to cover all Arabic chars with unicode Arabic character representatives

```
/^[\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669a-zA-Z0-9-_.():&,'’ ]+$/
```

But this is failing to select some characters from this word

مشروع – 1137 انشاء انبوب ترانسكو الجديد 1300 ملم في ساس النخل

it is only captureing first letter only.

[image]

Comment: It seems to [match fine](https://regex101.com/r/sAm7SH/1). You must be tricked by the highlighting bug. Did you try this in your code before posting the question? `/^[\u0621-\u064A\s]+$/.test('مشروع')` says `true`.

Comment: Unicode range is bad

Comment: @Justinas Saying something "is bad" is bad. _Why_ is it "bad"?

Comment: @IMSoP It's bad because of reasons defined in linked answer. Should I copy all content or what?

Comment: @Justinas The only linked question I see shows two answers with Unicode ranges in them, nothing about them being "bad".

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Please check this, this is the entire regex and failing string
  https://regex101.com/r/rASZGW/1

Comment: @WimalWeerawansa Please [edit] your question to include that example. In future, make sure you pay attention to the "reproducible" part of [mcve] - after coming up with a simplified example, run that example to make sure it does demonstrate the problem you want help with.

Comment: Ok, you have a different regex and input string. Why should the string match? You are saying you want to support Arabic, but you have `a-zA-Z0-9-_.():&,'’` in the regex, so what is it supposed to match?

Comment: Apart from `a-zA-Z0-9-_.():&,'’` I need to match whole arabic contents

Comment: When i remove `$` its matching everything else but skips one word, this word is not matching, i need to include this word also.

Comment: `–` is an EN-dash. Try `/^[\w\s.():&,'’\p{Script=Arabic}—–-]+$/u`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nOfN1z/1). Well, your Arabic range is [working well](https://regex101.com/r/nOfN1z/2) in `^[\w\s.():&,'’\u0621-\u064A\u0660-\u0669—–-]+$`, so your question is not about supporting Arabic, but about matching any kind of Unicode hyphens.

Comment: Thanks @Wiktor Stribiżew this it. please post this as the answer, thanks a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57358321/why-unicode-character-minus-sign-u2212-is-not-in-regex-unicode-group-ppd seems to be the answer for this question, no need answering.